# A Few Questions

Tags: usage

I have been trying to teach myself French for a year and I can read French books just fine, so I decide to work on reverse translation thinking it might help me with my poor sentence forming skills. I don't know any French speaking people, but I have a few questions that I couldn't find exact answers to in books or on google, maybe because they're silly questions, I'm not really sure. Anyhow, first question / example which I'm taking from one of my language books:

Permettez-moi de vous en prêter un peu (argent).

Is there a way in a sentence like this or similar ones that I might know how to choose between à and en? As when I was trying to translate that sentence from English to French I had thought it would be "à prêter", would that also be acceptable?

Second example:

De chez la modiste, sans doute?

The English sentence was, "From the modiste's no doubt?" So why chez there? I thought it would have been "de le" or "de le part" or "du".

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Please post one question at a time, with a meaningful title.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use the préposition ***à*** instead of the pronoun ***en***. *En* refers to *argent* here.

> *Permettez-moi de vous prêter peu **d'argent**.*

gives

> *Permettez-moi de vous **en** prêter un peu.*

---

In the second sentence, ***chez*** means **home/place/shop/**... :

> De **chez** la modiste, sans doute ?

and matches the genitive used in the English sentence:

> From the modiste'**s** no doubt?

i.e.:

> From the modiste'**s shop** no doubt?

Comment: First, thanks for the reply, I appreciate your time and effort in replying. With the second example, I understand the meaning of chez and how it is used in the sentence, I was hoping to understand more about making the proper choice of words, would any of my other examples to replace chez have been acceptable, or is there a specific reason why chez was used in that sentence? Thanks again.

Comment: *De la part de la modiste* is correct, but has a different meaning. Here, the modiste herself is giving something while with *chez*, the object just comes from the modiste's shop. The modiste herself might not have been there and/or aware of this fact. *De la modiste* is a little ambiguous, might mean *from the modiste* or *belonging to the modiste* or even *about the modiste*. It needs more context to be clear.

Comment: Thanks again for following up. I think I understand, so the reason chez was used is because it came from a shop or place of business rather than simply from a person?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point!